# Reference for triangle groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, fuchsian-groups

Can anyone suggest to me some references for studying triangle groups? Especially the existence of finite index subgroups, subgroups isomorphic to fundamental groups of compact surfaces etc.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group) is quite detailed, and contains relevant references.

Comment: This paper concerning the generic Euclidean case gives some information about the state of the art on both hyperbolic and Euclidean cases: https://oldmat.unicam.it/piergallini/home/papers/triangles.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are interested in “Fenchel’s conjecture” stating that (essentially) all two-orbifolds are finitely (orbifold) covered by surfaces. The case of triangle orbifolds is the hardest, and was solved by Ralph Fox (with, it seems, a few errors). See the 1983 paper by Chau titled [*A note concerning Fox’s paper on Fenchel’s conjecture*](https://doi.org/10.2307/2045442).